# Phone number validation not working on android phones

Tags: javascript, forms, validation

I have a form page where ppl can enter their details and then submit. 
There is a phone field where i have used the below  code and its working fine all computers, mobiles, ipads except android phone.

Its showing alert error even when user is typing only numbers. Can someone please help?

```
$("#phone").keydown(function (e) {
    if($.inArray(e.keyCode, [46, 8, 9, 27, 13, 110, 190]) !== -1 ||
        (e.keyCode === 65 && (e.ctrlKey === true || e.metaKey === true)) ||
        (e.keyCode >= 35 && e.keyCode <= 40)) {
          return;
    }
    if((e.shiftKey || (e.keyCode < 48 || e.keyCode > 57)) && (e.keyCode < 96 || 
        e.keyCode > 105)) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $.alert({ title: '&nbsp;', content: 'PHONE NUMBER MUST BE NUMBER FORMAT 
        ONLY.', type: 'red', typeAnimated: true, }); return false;
    }
 });
```

Comment: Here is the demo link.........   http://cartersarabia.com/dreamland/en/

Comment: maybe the keycodes are not the same on android. Why validating this way ? Why don't you use regexp ? That's easier to read, easier to maintain, easier to unit-test and surely more cross-platform.

Answer (score 0):

Consider using regular expression to validate a phone number.

```
$("#phone").on('keyup', function (e) {
    var val = this.value;

    // check value has non numeric characters
    if (!/^[0-9]*$/.test(val)) {
        $.alert({ ... });

        // remove non numeric characters from value
        this.value = val.replace(/[^0-9]+/g, ''); 
    }
});
```